# Writing render in different order results in null method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I write my code in this order

```
        <%= render @question.answers %>
    <%= render "answers/form" %>
```

It's acceptable, but if I do this order

```
        <%= render "answers/form" %>
        <%= render @question.answers %>
```

it results in an error, specifically at this line, and says > is undefined.

```
        <% if answer.created_at > Time.now.beginning_of_day %>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As already stated more information will help.

But it looks like you are trying to determine if the answer was created today.

I would do

    <% if answer.created_at.today? %>

But this is not the answer to your error message (but might hide the real problem)